# How can I specify values for parameters, when previewing a SSRS report in Visual Studio?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report project (created by someone else) opened in Visual Studio, and don't know how to preview it.

[image]

In the dataset (.rsd file) of the report,  it has a SQL script with two parameters: ConID and PayNo.
So when I click "Preview" in the top left corner (right to "Designer"), I got the error "The ConID parameter is missing a value". How can I specify values to the two parameters for previewing the report?

[image]

Here is my attempt, and let me know if I am in the right direction. I opened "Parameter Properties" of the first parameter, by right-clicking on "Contract Number" on the top left of the screenshot, and it shows its name is "ConID".

[image]

I am looking for where I can enter some value for this parameter, so I clicked "Available Values", then selected "Specify values", and then clicked "Add", and it asks me to type in "Label" and "Value". But I don't know what "Label" means here.

[image]

Comment: The Contract Number parameter needs a source for the Contract Number to display. In the Available Values tab, you can Specify Values that you want to use as a list - the Label field will show any tesxt you want to use instead of the ID (like WALMART Contract while the value would be the ID of the contract 1234). You probably want a query to get a list of your contract and use the Get Values from Query. See [MSDN - SSRS Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-parameter-to-your-report-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: There must have been a reason for the parameter to be set to "Hidden". Under the parameter setting, set the "Select Parameter Visibility:" to  Visible. when you preview your report now, it should allow you to enter the ID manually.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to get your report working is to take the script and run it directly in SQL without the parameters; ConID and PayNo. In your unfiltered results, pick a ConID and PayNo value combination to run in your SSRS report.

For testing, change the parameters visibility to "Visible" (second to last screenshot) so you can adjust the parameter values without leaving Preview mode. Now when you preview the report, those two parameter boxes should be blank and the report won't run until you provide values them. Enter any ConID and PayNo combination from your unfiltered result set.

If you want the parameters values to be populated when you run the report, you can enter them in the respective "Default Values" tab for each of the parameters . You do not need anything in "Available Values" tab.

Note - if this was a report in production, then it probably has it's parameters values passed by another report, which explains why the parameter visibility was set to hidden with no default values. Make sure to revert back to those settings when you are done testing.